# is it possible to optimize submatrixes operations in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vectorization

I'm working on a project and i'm doing additions on diagonal submatrixes of a square matrix of big size (180x180) with a "kernel" square matrix of size around 40*40.

```py
size1 = matrix1.shape[0] #square matrix shape 180x180
sizeKernel = kernelMatrix.shape[0] # square matrix shape 40x40
newMatrix1 = matrix1.copy()
np.fill_diagonal(newMatrix1, 0)
for i in range(size1):
      newMatrix1[i:i+sizeKernel,i:i+sizeKernel] += matrix1[i][i] * kernelMatrix[:size1-i, :size1-i]
```

The goal is to distribute diagonal coefficients with the kernel matrix to other coefficients (a kind of partial convolution).

As an example, let's say the matrix is size 4x4 and the kernel is size 2x2:

```
a = [[1,2,1,0],
     [3,-1,0,0],
     [0,1,1,1],
     [0,2,0,2]]

kern = [[1,2],
        [0,1]]
```

we create the matrix res by copying every coef of `a` but the diagonal coefs:

```
res = [[0,2,1,0],
       [3,0,0,0],
       [0,1,0,1],
       [0,2,0,0]]
```

we distribute every coefficient at diagonal to the bottom right submatrix of same size as kernel (if not possible we just take the remaining and cut the kernel matrix)
For the first coefficient of diagonal it gives:

```
res[0:2, 0:2] = res[0:2,0:2] + a[0,0]*kern

res[0:2, 0:2] = [[0,2]   +   1 * [[1,2],
                 [3,0]]           [0,1]]
                 
res = [[1,4,1,0],
       [3,1,0,0],
       [0,1,0,1],
       [0,2,0,0]]
```

Then we do the same idea for the other coefs. For the last coef of diagonal, instead of taking the whole kernel, we take apply the same thing extending the elements of the matrix with 0s.

As it is not vectorized, it takes quite a long time to compute this.

Another way to compute this would be to use directly the scipy method fftconvolve or convolve2d only on the diagonal matrix extracted, and add the result to the matrix with 0s on the diagonal:

```py
newMatrix = matrix1.copy()
matrix1Size = matrix1.shape[0]
np.fill_diagonal(newMatrix , 0)
newMatrix += scipy.signal.fftconvolve(matrix1, kernelMatrix)[:matrix1Size,:matrixSize]
```

but it takes approximately as much time as the first method (of course their are more calculation if we do the full convolution of a whole matrix)

Is there any method to vectorize this calculation on submatrixes?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `kernelMatrix` is of size 40x40 and `size1` is 180, so I do not see how the code can works. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Yes of course no problem, i have updated the post and set a little example. Tell me if you need more infos